# Intersection of intervals is non empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[image]

For this theorem in Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin, what if I take $I_n$ to be $(-1/n, 1/n)$ ? Won't the intersection be a null set then?

Comment: $0\in I_n$ for all $n$, hence $0\in\bigcap I_n$.

Comment: It seems that something is missing from the statement of this Theorem.  Perhaps in the context it is assumed that "intervals" are closed intervals.  In any event the nested intervals $I_n=(0,1/n)$ for $n=1,2,3.\ldots$ will satisfy $\cap_1^\infty I_n$ being empty.

Comment: The proof of Theorem 2.38 shows that Rudin has closed intervals in mind. In his later *Real and complex analysis* he calls open intervals *segments*.

Comment: I found it hard to believe that Rudin would not specify that the intervals are closed.  But sure enough, he doesn't do so in the statement!  Compare also the discussion on p. 31, which includes definitions of the **interval** $[a,b]$, the **segment** $(a,b)$ and a remark that "half-open intervals" (quotations in the original) will occasionally appear.  Hmm.  On the one hand I find it hard to believe that students would not be confused by these conventions.  On the other hand, I've owned the book for more than 20 years and never noticed this until now.